# Twitter API statuses_count include retweets or not?

Tags: api, twitter

In twitter API "users/show", there is a statuses_count, does it include retweet, or not? One issue about twitter API is that they don't have an exact definition for each of the items in the returned result. You can only guess the meaning by the name.

Answer (score 6):

It includes retweets. Manual testing.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, so there is no document for the returned objects for the APIs, manual testing is the only way to find out?

Comment: I've searched their API, I couldn't find any useful info. I retweeted a tweet and observed that my total tweets increased by 1.

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object.html